# How to fetch Gmail contacts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I have a scenario in my current application where I want to fetch the Gmail id's of my users.
Could anyone tell me the way with piece of code in C#?

Note: I am developing a web-base application in asp.net with C#.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [google contacts api](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) there are C# sample there.

Comment: Sambo, the link is referring to an older verion - 1.0. The current is 3.0/2.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Google Accounts API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/).

[You can find an example here.](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the open source .Net library [gmailapi](http://www.johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/).The GmailAgent has a GetContacts method for retrieving all the contacts.