# How to access gmail contact in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, google-api, gmail, socialengine

how to get **gmail** contact with access token

```
http://www.example.com/social/emaillist.aspx?token=1%2F2sYPqU7nZCAGqU-LvsHZ-1m1kdEOJxmHsReSK1SpwSM
```

I'm here the all access and permissions but contact are not displaying using this code.

Comment: it may helpful http://gnillydev.blogspot.in/2007/10/yahoo-contact-import-class-in-c.html

Comment: use this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999766/how-to-fetch-gmail-contacts

Comment: can any one explain with example an i'm tried to use different -  different examples

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use openAuth so you can get information from their API